# No Model Found for 'user_id' Ember-Data issue

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

For some reason I keep getting this error when trying to create a record using ember store.

Here is the error: `Uncaught Error: No model was found for 'user_id'`

Here is my actions function that causes the error. I've removed `user_id` and anything that uses the `user` model from the model as well as from the creation and it still gives me the same error. I simply can't figure out what's causing the error, the error itself isn't very informative either. It's not giving me any line numbers that are causing the error in my code.

```
addProposal: function() {
    var store = this.store;
    var self = this;

    var foundUser = function(user) {
        console.log(user);
        var proposal = store.createRecord('proposal', {
            discount_code: self.get('discount_code'),
            user_id: user,
            status_id: self.get('status_id'),
            timeline: self.get('timeline'),
            expiry_dt: self.get('expiry_dt'),
            company_name: self.get('company_name'),
            client_email: self.get('client_email'),
            proposal_needed_by: self.get('proposal_needed_by'),
            data_needed_by: self.get('data_needed_by'),
            proposal_expiry_dt: self.get('proposal_send_dt'),
            liason_id: user,
            qb_id: self.get('qb'),
            version: self.get('version'),
            custom_discount: self.get('custom_discount'),
            notes: self.get('notes'),
        });


        var onSuccess = function(proposal) {
            console.log('Proposal was created');

            this.transitionToRoute('proposal', proposal);
        };

        var onFailure = function() {
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        };

        proposal.save().then(onSuccess, onFailure);

    };

    store.find('user', $.cookie('user_id')).then(foundUser);

    //console.log(this.get('statuses'));

}
```

Here is my proposal model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

var attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;

export default DS.Model.extend({
    discount_code: attr(),

    user_id: belongsTo('user', {async: true}),
    user: Ember.computed.alias('user_id'),


    status_id: belongsTo('status', {async: true}),
    status: Ember.computed.alias('status_id'),


    timeline: attr(),
    proposal_needed_by: attr(),
    data_needed_by: attr(),
    proposal_expiry_dt: attr(),

    company_name: attr(),
    client_name: attr(),
    client_email: attr(),
    sent_dt: attr(),

    liason_id: belongsTo('user', {async: true}),
    // Semantically better
    liason: Ember.computed.alias('liason_id'),

    qb_id: belongsTo('user', {async: true}),
    qb: Ember.computed.alias('qb_id'),

    version: attr(),
    custom_discount: attr(),
    notes: attr(),
    created_at: attr(),
    friendly_date: function() {
        return moment(this.get('created_at')).format('MMM Do YY, h:mm a');
    }.property('created_at'),


    updated_at: attr(),
    comments: hasMany('comment', {async: true}),
    logs: hasMany('log', {async: true}),
});
```

Comment: Just to let you know, there's an issue with setting async belongs to,  https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1542#issuecomment-33594385 and https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1535

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the server is returning a hash with key `user_ids`, causing ember to look for a model called `user_id`, whereas in your case the server should be returning the key `users`.

If you can't change the server you can write a custom adapter which will change the key name in the payload coming from the server.

Comment: Sadly this is not the case, my server is returning something like this for /users `{"users": [{..}, {..}]}` and /user/1 `{"user": {"id" .. }}`